# jQuery Templates MIME type

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, templates

Which is the correct MIME type to use for a jQuery Template, for both ASP.NET MVC and HTML:

```
type="x-jquery-tmpl"
```

OR

```
type="text/html"
```

I have seen both used. For Example:

http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/ uses the first MIME type and http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/05/07/jquery-templates-and-data-linking-and-microsoft-contributing-to-jquery.aspx uses the second...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either is fine; it's arbitrary.  The key is *not* to use a type that the browser interprets as script, such as text/javascript.